# Mount-SPContentDatabase error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, restore, content-database

I have recieved a copied database from a live farm and am trying to restore this database to my development environment. I have created a new web application and site collection and have restored the database to my development sql instance.

I am now running the command

> "Mount-SPContentDatabase "Name of database" -DatabaseServer
>   "DBServerName" -WebApplication "name of web app"

However I get the following error when I run this command.

> Mount-SPContentDatabase : This content database has a schema version which is not supported in this farm

What should I check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The farm you received the database from is most likely at a different patch level than the farm you are trying to mount it to. Get the systems to the same patch level and then try mounting the database again.

Also, you will most likely want to remove the root site collection from your development environment because if you are trying to restore a root site collection it will see that one already exists and default so that the one already there stays in tact. You would get a successful attach but you won't see your site collection. If this happens, unattach the DB, delete the site collection, and mount it again.

Comment: Guys I have checked the patch levels and they are different. Updated the patch on my local machine and this works great!

Answer (score 2):

Compare your development and production farms. Check the version of the configuration database (farm) on this page and compare the two farms. You can do this right in Central Admin by

> System Settings > Manager servers

If patch levels are different then you need to upgrade your development environment (patch level) to the same level as production